# How do I make the rational numbers 0 and 1/2 in lean4?

Tags: lean4, beginner

I'm trying to define a function that in python I would write:

```python
def f(x: bool) -> float:
    if x:
        return 0.5
    return 0.0
```

In lean 4 I tried writing this (this is the whole file):

```
def f (b : Bool) : Rat :=
match b with
| false => 0
| true => 0.5
```

But I get type errors:

```
failed to synthesize instance
  OfNat Rat 0
failed to synthesize instance
  OfScientific Rat
```

It seems to be having trouble turning the number literals I wrote into the type `Rat` that I want. Probably I just need to invoke some conversion method on the literals to do the cast, but I don't know what that method is called and it's unfortunately basically impossible to google for the names of methods this basic.

Comment: I think the issue might be that `Rat` doesn't actually exist and is being interpreted as the name of a constraint instead of the name of an actual type? In that case what is the type actually called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You unfortunately ran into the dark side of [auto-implict arguments](https://lean-lang.org/lean4/doc/autobound.html).  Since `Rat` wasn’t in scope, Lean automatically added it as an implicit parameter.

[`Rat`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Std/Data/Rat/Basic.html#Rat) can be found in `Std.Data.Rat` (you need to make sure the [standard library](https://github.com/leanprover/std4) is included in your project).

```
import Std.Data.Rat

def f (b : Bool) : Rat := if b then 0.5 else 0

#eval f true  -- (1 : Rat)/2
#eval f false -- 0
```

A good way to look this stuff up is in the [mathlib documentation](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs), which is more than just mathlib.
Lean also has other number types like [`Float`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Data/Float.html#Float) (good for computation, but annoying for proofs) and [`Real`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Data/Real/Basic.html#Real) (good for proofs, but can’t be used for computation).  `Rat` is indeed a good middle ground between the two.

Comment: Whoever thought that default auto-implicits were a good idea is going to the fifth circle.

Comment: Related, does " Real (good for proofs, but can’t be used for computation)" mean I cannot construct a real number in lean? like `def c : Real := 3`?